# For IE9, the tabs only change when I click the tabs, not when I click the text on the tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have a set of tabs for IE9. I want the active tab to be white with orange text and the inactive tab to be gray with black text.

On the hover, which works, you have to click the tab to change the tab. But to change the color of the text, you have to click only on the text.  Clicking the text does not change the tab and clicking the tab doesn’t change the color of the text. They are not connected.  I am looking to change the color of the text and tab when the text is clicked or the tab is clicked. They need to be connected. You can see the action here:
 
    http://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/v43c9a9m/

```
$(function() {
  $("b").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("b").addClass("font2").not(this).removeClass("font2");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are adding : `e.preventDefault();`

```js
//Updated Function..
$(function() {
    $(".tab-label").click(function(e) {
    $(".tab-label").find('b').removeClass("font2");
    $(this).find('b').addClass("font2");
    });
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.tabs:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.tabs .tab {
  display: inline;
}

.tabs .tab-label {
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 1.00);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  left: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.tabs .tab > [type="radio"] {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 1px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tabs .tab-panel {
  display: inline;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.tabs .tab-content {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabs .tab [type="radio"]:checked + .tab-label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabs .tab [type="radio"]:checked ~ .tab-panel {
  display: inline;
}

.tabs a {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-left: 1px solid #ff0000;
  border-right: 1px solid #ff0000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
  display: inline;
}

.tabs a:hover,
.tabs a.active {
  background: #666;
  color: black;
}

.tabContent {
  border: 1px solid #4cff00;
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 500px;
}

#day2 {
  margin-top: -24px;
}

#day3 {
  margin-top: -48px;
}

.center-image {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .3;
  width: 90%;
  left: 170px;
  top: -75px;
  z-index: 10;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}

.text-glow {
  /*text-shadow: -3px 0px 10px #FFF, 3px 0px 10px #FFF, 0px 0px 10px #FFF, -3px -3px 10px #FFF, 3px -3px 10px #FFF, 0px -3px 10px #FFF, -3px 3px 10px #FFF, 3px 3px 10px #FFF, 0px 3px 10px #FFF;
        */
  z-index: 20;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

.main2 {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 97%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 25px;
}

th,
td {
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(197, 232, 255, .2);
}

.font {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.font:hover,
.font:active,
.font:focus,
.font:visited,
.font:link .font2 {
  color: rgba(255, 117, 0, 1.00);
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.name {
  min-width: 350px !important;
}

.right-image {
  /*background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top right;
        background-image: url("~/Content/Images/Untitled-1.png");
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(167,218,255,0.20),white );
        background-image: url("~/content/images/Untitled-1.png");*/
  width: 510px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 50;
}

.tabs {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.tabs a {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-left: 1px solid #ff0000;
  border-right: 1px solid #ff0000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
  display: inline;
}

.tabs a:hover,
.tabs a.active {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabContent {
  border: 1px solid #4cff00;
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 500px;
}

.center-image {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1.0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0px;
  top: -10px;
  /*  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
        background-image: url("~/Content/Images/banner3.png")no-repeat;*/
}

.center-image > img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text-glow {
  /*text-shadow: -3px 0px 10px #FFF, 3px 0px 10px #FFF, 0px 0px 10px #FFF, -3px -3px 10px #FFF, 3px -3px 10px #FFF, 0px -3px 10px #FFF, -3px 3px 10px #FFF, 3px 3px 10px #FFF, 0px 3px 10px #FFF;
        */
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
}

.font2 {
  color: rgba(255, 117, 0, 1.00);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-1"> <b class="font">Day 1 - July 19, 2016</b></label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <table>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-2">
        <b class="font">Day 2 - July 20, 2016</b>
        </label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <table>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-3"> <b class="font">Day 3 - July 21, 2016</b></label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <table>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I can still click a tab and not the text, and the text does not change color with the tab I clicked. I need the text to change color in accordance with the tab changing.

Comment: @LanceB See my updated answer, i've updated your function to work when click on tabs or labels